# Logcat filter in Android

Tags: android, adt

I am trying to select a line which is filtered for the text. When I remove the line text my selected line will not be focused on screen. What is the best way to view the upper and lower lines of the filtered text.
I am using Eclipse and latest ADT for Android.

Hope you will understand my problem and trying to solve my problem.

Example:

```
I have some logs for my application.
I write in Logs filter "ABC MSG"
Now, I can see only logs which have "ABC MSG" text.
I select a particular line
Now, I want to see the top tow lines of my selection but may be those lines have no "ABC MSG"
When I remove the text from the filter box, my windows start from the last line and scrolling start.
Where is my selection.
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? not able to get the exact problem...

Answer (score 0):

In Debug (Eclipse) select Create Filter (the green cross), and add your filter text.